# How can I compile prolog code in ubuntu?

Tags: prolog

How can I compile or run below these two files under gprolog or swi-prolog?

I have two files:

sample.pl:

```
foo ( arg1, arg2 ) :- !, a ( arg1 ).
```

test.pl:

```
a(1).
a(2).
a(3).
a(4).
a(5).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "consult" command to load and compile files.

```
consult(test).
```

In order to load several files, you need to consult each file in its own command. These commands should do the trick for you.

```
consult(sample).
consult(test).
```

Comment: When I call sample.pl with consult, it gives error Syntax error: Operator expected
. Why ?

Comment: The syntax error is related to the compiling process. You do have an empty space between "foo" and the following parenthesis - this is a syntax error. If you remove that space, it will compile correctly - at least it does here...

Comment: @user1423470 note that instead of consulting each file separately you can do it (at least in swi-prolog) by giving a list of files: `consult([sample,test]).`

Comment: and better yet, you could include the file to test in the testing file: `:- [sample].` put at the top of the `test` file and then you'd just have to load `test`: `[test].`

Comment: Woah, stop optimizing :D but yeah that would be a nice addition too

Answer (score 2):

its kind of just syntactic sugar but you can also use

```
    ['file.pl'].
```

that will compile a prolog file